# Random number generation, two different methods?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does anyone know the differences between the two methods of random number generation used in the following code?  My suspicion is the first case may be more computationally expensive because it's getting a new seed from `/dev/urandom` every time a random number is generated.  Also appreciate any comments if I'm generating random numbers correctly in these examples.

I'm confused because [uniform_int_distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()/) specifies `template<class URNG> result_type operator()(URNG& g);` and in some examples I see the parameter passed to be of the type [default_random_engine](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/) and other time [random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/random_device).  This adds confusion to what `default_random_engine` actually does.

For example, method 1 I have seen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> p{0,9};

    map<int,int> m;
    for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        m[p(rd)]++;
    }

    for (map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin();
         it != m.end(); ++it)
        cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Method 2,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> p{0,9};

    map<int,int> m;
    for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        m[p(gen)]++;
    }

    for (map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin();
         it != m.end(); ++it)
        cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first method is simply bad. Your hardware has limited entropy, and you want to waste it like that? The second method can be improved with a PRNG that's better than `default_random_engine` which I believe is implementation-defined.

Comment: Don't *ever* use `default_random_engine`. You don't know what you'll get. You might get a linear congruential generator (or worse). Name the random engine you *want*, explicitly - and *seed* it properly. `mt19937_64` is a good default choice if you have no clue why you should choose something else.

Comment: What is the PRNG like `default_random_engine` actually doing?  I see on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/operator()/ that it uses `x = (a*x + c) mod m`, but no idea what parameters `x, a,c, m` are based on that pages description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method is bad practice, and the second is preferred. Although, in the second method, `default_random_engine` is typically not recommended unless it's for experimenting or some other non-important reason. The big reason is that's implementation-defined, so it will differ based on compiler, and it generally is not robust at all, just simple.

The reasoning that the first method is bad is that `std::random_device` polls your hardware's source of true randomness. This is a limited supply. The better practice is to use it as a completely unpredictable seed to a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG). This is why the second example is better.

I've made a couple changes to your second example. The main change is that I don't need to declare a `random_device` to sit around on the stack, and I use `std::mt19937` which is probably the most common PRNG you'll see in C++ code.

None of the C++ Standard Library PRNGs are considered sufficient for cryptographic purposes; you'd need an external library for that.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main() {
  std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> p{0, 9};

  std::map<int, int> m;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    m[p(gen)]++;
  }

  for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"polls your hardware's source of true randomness"* Or it should do so (\*cough\* MinGW \*cough\*).

Comment: Right, didn't feel that it needed raising for this answer though.

Comment: Does uniform_int_distribution{}() modify the passed in random engine?  I noticed that the overload() is not a const for the parameter.  Trying to understand if / how state is maintained in any of these objects.

Comment: I can't speak to that as I've never needed to know. Encapsulation and all that. It seems very natural that the PRNG will have to change its state after generating a value, though. Same with the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The std library offers a set of [Predefined random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random#Predefined_random_number_generators) that gives certain guarantees about the values generated. One of them is `default_random_engine` which is implementation-defined (so you need to check how the vendor of the library implemented it).

To have a reliable generator (consistent results between the different vendors) you would choose one of the others like `mt19937`.

The random numbers you get from `random_device` are normally only used as a seed for the chosen random number generator.  For `random_device` you have a similar problem as with `default_random_engine` as it is not specified how the values are generated.

The idea behind this is that `random_device` provides good enough values for a seed in general but not for not good enough for a proper generator.

If you know the specific hardware your program is running on and the library, and you know that `random_device` creates random numbers based on a good source, then it might be an option, but if you create an application that is used on different OS and unknown hardware, then `random_device` won't be an option as a generator.

Comment: So the `random_device` acts as some seed and the numbers the generator generates are pseudo random?  Makes me wonder how often a seed needs to be updated.

Comment: @notaorb you set the seed only once at the beginning. And depending on if the randomness should be reproducible for every run, you either use a constant value for the seed or a random one.